How are you supposed to level at the endgame of SMTV: Vengeance?
How are you supposed to level at the endgame of Shin Megami Tensei V: Vengeance?
I assume I'm at the endgame of Shin Megami Tensei V: Vengeance. I've got to get through the last story bosses. I've done the sidequests and area explorations I've found and generally avoided grinding outside of the level spike when reaching Da'at Taito. I've reached the Empyrean, and I feel a bit like my game has bricked.
I'm level 79, and the only remaining quests I've found are the level 99 Demi-fiend and level 87 Samael quests. I'm too low-level to enter the Shiva superboss. The highest level demons to kill are back at the Temple of Eternity, which are below my level, so EXP gain from killing them is very inefficient.
Does the game expect me to spend all my gospels, grimoires, and macca at this point?

Yep, seems like gospels are the way, given the answers on this Steam Discussion:
(Spoiler) Where to farm good xp after level 80, in the end game now? 
If you're against / don't have DLC like this answerer:

MESeele [has Shin Megami Tensei V: Vengeance] 25 Jun @ 4:32am
...
The best method is to have saved your gospels until you had enough to go directly to 99. Which, does not help you if you've already been using them.
...
Otherwise, you can go Mitama hunting, VR if you have a playthrough completed already, or just having Riberama up and getting consecutive battles against Chi You/ball angel/Yamata no Orochi.

